# How to produce clean DataFrame from pivot table in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I have next question.

For example I have next DataFrame in Pandas

```
 a  b  c 
'x' 1 100
'y' 2 100
'z' 3 100
```

Now I want create from the values in column `a` the header of new DataFrame, the values in column `b` are correspondig values in the first row and column `c` I use for the index. 
Currently I use the next code:

```
import pandas
piv = df.pivot(index='c', columns='a')
new_df = pandas.DataFrame(piv.to_records())
```

The output is not enough fit for me, because I have `b` in the column names of a new DataFrame. Probably somebody can tell me here a better solution to obtain exactly the next output:

```
index 'x' 'y' 'z'
 100   1   2   3
```

Should be not a pivot table, just a real DataFrame.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to add the values operator to the pivot function:

```
piv = df.pivot(index='c', columns='a', values='b')
```

full example:

```
piv = df.pivot(index='c', columns='a', values='b')
new_df = pd.DataFrame(piv.to_records()).rename(columns={'c':'index'})
new_df

    index   'x' 'y' 'z'
0   100      1   2   3
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I want. Just missed this possibility with values parameter...